# My JSON data, which I am trying to extract, only key values which contains true as its value

Tags: .net, json

My json data

```
"BLANK"   : false,
"3NWK"    : true,
"3RWK"    : false,
"3LK"     : true,
"3WCBPK"  : false,
"3WLPK"   : false,
"2DGZK"   : true
```

The logic which I have written

```
  parsedMessage = new JObject
     (
     new JProperty("parsedMsg", parsedMsgMerge)
     );

                    foreach (JObject parsedObject in  parsedMessage )
                    {
                        foreach (JProperty parsedProperty in parsedObject.Properties())
                        {
                            string propertyName = parsedProperty.Name;
                            string propertyValue = (string)parsedProperty.Value;

                            if (propertyValue.Equals("true"))
                            {
                                // string propertyValue = (string)parsedProperty.Value;

                                Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}, Value: {1}", propertyName, propertyValue);


                           }

                        }
                    }
                    Console.ReadLine();
```

I am getting this error while running

> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The best
>   overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments
>   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Type , Object )

Comment: question is unclear, please elaborate

Comment: yeah sure,here i am reciving data from console in json formate(key:value pair in that i need to sort the key value pair based on some condition like (which ever property values are true i need to fetch that)